# store word by word from a file with using Stream<T>

Tags: java, stream

I'm learning to use Stream, and trying to get all words that contain vowels and the length of the word is greater than 4 in a file without Scanner.hasNext().

[image: example text in a file]

For the example of the file, I wanna write code like

```
Stream<String> text = Files.lines(Paths.get(example.txt));
List<String> result = text.filter(w->w.length()>4)
.filter(w -> w.contains("a")||w.contains("e")||
w.contains("i")||w.contains("o")||w.contains("u")).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

The output that I want to get is

```
There bunch vowels example vowel
```

But it returns the same string as the text.

All I know is to read line by line in a text file with using Stream, but I want to make it read word by word (or split strings from each line.)

Anyone please help me?

Comment: @MikeFHay you're right, I might made a mistake. But I wanna handle it word by word, not line by line anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below snippet

```
List<String> result = Files.lines(Paths.get("/tmp/examples.txt"))
                                   .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\W+")))
                                   .filter(w -> w.length() > 4)
                                   .filter(w -> w.matches(".*[aeiou].*"))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

**Regex to split the word:** `"\\W+"` : one or more sequences of non-word character.

*Note:*
The problem with this approach is the word `foo'sbar`will be split into 2 words `foo` and `sbar`. If you want to exclude `'` as a splitter, you can use the pattern `[\W&&[^']]+`. Please include all the valid characters this way in the expression.

**Output:**

```
[There, bunch, vowels, example, vowel]
```